# Paypal SetExpressCheckout won't return to "RETURN URL"

Tags: paypal, returnurl

I'm trying to set up a paypal solution but i'm having some trouble with the RETURNURL.

My form looks like this.

```
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp"> 
<input type="hidden" name="USER" value="<%=PayPal_API_Username%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="<%=PayPal_API_Password%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="<%=PayPal_API_Signature%>">
<input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="65.0">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale"> 
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" value="DKK"> 
<input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="<%=Amount%>.00"> 
<input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM" value="<%=GUID%>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="http://<%=c_mainDomain%>/return.html"> 
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="http://<%=c_mainDomain%>/cancel.html">
<input type="hidden" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Videre til betaling med Paypal"> 
</form>
```

When i submit the form it goes to "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp" and shows the message below.

TOKEN=EC%2d2XR31554RN094031R&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d01%2d03T10%3a23%3a11Z&CORRELATIONID=a0c80a35bfde2&ACK=Success&VERSION=65%2e0&BUILD=2271164

Shouldn't it send me back to my own page, to the "RETURNURL"? or is there something i'm missing

Comment: I've worked with paypal API some time ago - I don't remember the details right now. But sending the API password by user's browser form looks quite suspicious. I feel that this POST should be done by your web server - not by client's browser. Check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I'm pretty sure, that my comment was right.
This POST should be done by your web app server - transient to the client.
Just before the user clicks the 'pay' button (when you render the site) on your web app - you call the setExpressCheckout, then you read the token from the answer and apply it to the button.
Then after the user clicks he is redirected to paypal site and returns to your page by returnURL.

Please make sure you exactly understand the whole process. Giving too much information to your users may be a potential vulnerability to your payments module.

EDIT: I guess that the form you've created is from [PayPal's tutorial](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted). Please notice that it is for testing and understanding the whole process only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont know what i was thinking, offcause i shouldn't display the form on the client side.

Do you know if there is any sample code i classic ASP. I dont know how to call the "setExpressCheckout"

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I worked with PayPal API two years ago. I'm quite unable to help you. I think you should rely only on their documentation. It's quite good, but may be too much info at the beginning. I think you should use some simple HTTP(s) client library in ASP. Maybe this is in .NET standard? Just to perform this POST and parse the result. I've used Jakarta's HttpClient but it was in J2EE.

Comment: There's some fairly easy sample code up at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code -- look at ECSetExpressCheckout, ECGetExpressCheckout and ECDoExpressCheckout which calls the SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API's, respectively (all three API calls are required).

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution in classic ASP. It looks like that i have to use the component "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"